# Very short question about the circuits in the figure?

Tags: diodes

We have the circuit in the figure.In my book it says Vo=Vi.Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no current flow in the circuit. The terminals can just show voltages. The negative portion of Vo is directly connected with Vi and the positive portion is connected likewise. Here you can be confused with the resistor. As there is no current flow in the circuit, the drop through the resistor is zero. Thus in the circuit Vi = Vo

Answer (score 0):

Because the battery is disconnected and no current is being drawn by anything. Therefore no voltage drop between Vin and Vout

Comment: I don't Think there will be a voltage drop at Vi even when the battery connects to a load . since R is in series between Vo and Vi which will only responsible for controlling the current flowing to Vi from Vo.

Comment: @SanjeevKumar, once the switch is closed, Vo is 10V, because of the ideal voltage source.

Comment: @The Photon:yes :-)

Answer (score 0):

With the switch open, we can write an equation for \$V_O\$ in terms of \$V_I\$ and the output current \$I_O\$ (where the output current is left to right through the resistor \$R\$):

$$V_O = V_I - I_O\cdot R$$

This is just an elementary application of KVL and Ohm's law.

Clearly, in the case that \$I_O = 0\$ (the output is an open circuit), we have

$$V_O = V_I - 0\cdot R = V_I$$

In words, if there is no current through the resistor, there is no voltage difference across the resistor and, thus, \$V_O = V_I\$

Comment: @ Alfred Centauri: As per you there will be a voltage drop once the switch is connected? means Vi will not be equal to Vo?

Comment: @SanjeevKumar, note that I begin my answer with *"With the switch open"*.  With the switch closed, we have an entirely different equation, \$V_O = 10V\$ independent of the voltage across the resistor.  Indeed, the voltage across the resistor is then \$V_R = V_I - 10V\$.